# PHP - Firebase Database Path Containing Spaces - Admin SDK

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm new to PHP. Actually I've just started using it to manage my database for my Android app. So the problem is in case I want to edit an item. I check first if it exists so I can load its info in a new page. Here's the function I used to do it (after Firebase initialization):

```
function findMovie($database){
    $snapshot = $database->getReference('Movies/'.$_POST['movieType'])->getSnapshot();
    if ($snapshot->hasChild($_POST['movieName'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
    else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role = "alert" >
                <strong>Error!</strong> A movie with the given name, <a href="#" class="alert-link">, cannot be found</a>.
            </div >';
        echo "Movie Name: ".$_POST['movieName'];
    }
}
```

The problem is if the item has a space in its name, an **error** occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught JmesPath\SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error at character 4 The Revenant ^ Did not reach the end of the token stream in...
```

And it works perfectly if it doesn't!

Here's the path in my database:

[image]

I tried with **hello**, and it works fine... Is there a solution?

Comment: I'd suggest not using names as keys in your data structure. Besides the issue with spaces and possibly special characters, you will get in trouble as soon as you have movies sharing the same name.

Comment: I'm the only one who can share movies so I'm making sure each node has a unique key... Also if the movie already exist.. An if statement will notify me to change its name... i'm using their names as a keys to make it esier to access the same movie throught different sections of the app (on Android), access movie details and stuff in different nodes of my database.. and make it easier to edit them as well. So is there any solution to access nodes with spaces? No special characters will be included.